# Jenkins Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a boolean parameter named `MyTests` as part of the build job. The job calls a Groovy script. I believe the particular code below is causing a problem within the script. Any idea on the proper way in Groovy to reference a boolean within an if statement.

```
stage("post_build") {
     if (${params.MyTests}) {
         my_code_block...
        }
```

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `${...}` and write `param.MyTests` directly. The `${...}` should only be used when referencing a variable (or regular groovy/java expression) **inside** a string. So:

```
def foo = "bar"
echo foo
echo "Withing a string: ${foo}"
```

So in you're case:

```
stage("post_build") {
    if (params.MyTests) {
        my_code_block...
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Would setting the above automatically evaluate to True or do I need to add = true?..

Comment: No, ´params.MyTests` will be a `boolean` object, see quote in Gerold Broser's answer below, basically objects in `params` will have object corresponding to the parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

See [Pipeline Syntax, Flow Control](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control):

```
stage('Example') {
    if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
        echo 'I only execute on the master branch'
    }
}
```

and [JENKINS-27295](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27295):

> I would say that it is a best practice to always use the `params` object if you want the ensure that the type is consistent. Referencing the parameter as either `foo` or `env.foo` returns the value as it was injected into an environment variable and will always be of type `String`.
>
> ```
> properties([parameters([booleanParam(defaultValue: false, description: '', name: 'foo')])])
>
> echo "foo: " + foo.getClass().toString()
> echo "env.foo: " +  env.foo.getClass().toString()
> echo "params.foo: " + params.foo.getClass().toString()
> ```
>
> returns:
>
> ```
> [Pipeline] echo
> foo: class java.lang.String
> [Pipeline] echo
> env.foo: class java.lang.String
> [Pipeline] echo
> params.foo: class java.lang.Boolean
> [Pipeline]
> ```